# ERROR: req.logIn is not a function Passport Js MERN STACK

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, mern, passport-local

I am trying use passport-local to authenticate user for a MERN Stack project. Currently I am unable to LOG IN or LOG OUT and I keep getting errors like this:

**TypeError: req.logIn is not a function** & **req.logOut is not a function**

I am not sure why is this happening. I have been following the Passport Js documentation. What should I do to fix this?
Thank you

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passport = require("passport");
const passportLocal = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const initialize = require("./passport-config");
const session = require("express-session");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const User = require("./modules/User");
const port = XXXXX;

mongoose.connect(
  "XXXXXXXXXX",
  { useNewUrlParser: true },
  () => console.log("Mongoose Connected"),
);

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "secret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
  }),
);

passport.use(passport.initialize());
passport.use(passport.session());
initialize(passport);

app.get("/users", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello");
});

app.post("/users/create", (req, res) => {
  User.findOne(
    { username: req.body.username },
    async (err, doc) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      if (doc) {
        res.json({
          auth: false,
          message: "User Already Exist",
        });
      } else {
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(
          req.body.password,
          10,
        );

        const newUser = User({
          username: req.body.username,
          password: hashedPassword,
        });

        await newUser.save();

        res.json({
          auth: true,
          message: "User Created",
        });
        console.log("User Created");
      }
    },
  );
});

app.get("/users/logout", (req, res) => {
  req.logOut();
  res.send(true);
  console.log("Logged Out");
});

app.post("/users/login", (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate("local", (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }

    if (!user) {
      res.json({
        auth: true,
        message: "Cannot Log In",
      });
    }

    req.logIn(user, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      res.json({
        auth: true,
        message: "User Logged In",
      });
      console.log("Successfully Logged In");
    });
  })(res, req, next);
});

app.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`Server started on port: ${port}`),
);
```

Comment: The functions are [`req.login()` and `req.logout()`](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/login/), not `logIn` and `logOut`.

Comment: @AKX Passport exposes a login() function on req (also aliased as logIn()) that can be used to establish a login session.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
passport.use(passport.initialize());
passport.use(passport.session());
initialize(passport);
```

1. it is not passport.use it should be app.use and
2. the initialize passport should be called first.

```
initialize(passport);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Comment: How do you know what `initialize(passport)` does?

Comment: Hi @DimaParzhitsky. http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/  most of the times it contains different auth strategies and some customizations related to those strategies. 
https://github.com/AshutoshPatole/backends/blob/master/authentication/routes/passportConfig.js this might give you an idea of what initialize(passport) contains in context of this question.